# preventing hardcoded url to delete in django

Tags: django

I have a link and button inside it that deletes a record associated with the button

```
<a href="{% url 'parts:stock_delete' stock.id  %}">
  <button class="delete" type="submit" name="delete_btn" style="position: absolute; right: 40px;" >Delete</button>
</a>
```

but I want the record to be deleted only when the button is pressed but not when URL is typed in the address bar like:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/parts/stock_delete/16/

what can be done for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview)!

It's a generic class-based view that - when viewed (`GET`) will display a confirmation page asking if you really want to delete the record. When you confirm (`POST`) the record will be deleted.

@sasuke's answer doesn't take into consideration another large security hole, [CSRF](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/). You'll want to study this page very closely if you want to ensure that your application is secure.

Comment: thanks @Kye for pointing out the security hole. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `post` method. And when the button is pressed, you can pass some flag, say `flag1`.

```
<form action="{% url 'parts:stock_delete' stock.id  %}" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="flag1" value="True" >{% csrf_token %}
    <button class="delete" type="submit" name="delete_btn" style="position: absolute; right: 40px;" >Delete</button></a>
</form>
```

and in the backend you can write like this in your function in views.py.

```
# delete view
....
if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'flag1' in request.POST:
        ... # deleted your object here
```

Comment: how to use post method in <a> ?

Comment: You can submit a form on button click or you can send an `Ajax` to do the same.

Comment: @rajivshah don't use an `<a>` if you want to use a `<button>`

Comment: You should use a DELETE method in your form rather than a POST. It's a more appropriate method for doing deletion.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as Kye said, use DeleteView via post to exclude the registry. There is a concern with CSRF, but Django already provides a way for AJAX requests to bring the token. You can check in the documentation:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request